# CodenameOne TextView Foreground Color

Tags: colors, textfield, codenameone

I'm new to codename one and try to set the foreground (text) color of a TextView. Setting it to red color and writing a text after pressing a  button works. The code is executed in button's action listener method:

```
mValueField.getStyle().setFgColor(0xFF0000); // set red color
mValueField.setText("Fill in!"); // write info text
```

After setting focus into the field the text should disappear and color should be black again. The code is executed in TextField's focusGained() method:

```
mValueField.setText(""); // clear info text
mValueField.getStyle().setFgColor(0x000000); // set black color
```

Problem is that the text disappears but new chars are still red instead of black.

Any solutions for me?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `getStyle()` it's designed for use within `paint()` or similar methods. Since the component has multiple states you need to customize every individual state e.g. `getUnselectedStyle()`, `getSelectedStyle()` etc.

Or you can use the `getAllStyles()` to set them all with a single call.